# AVPlayerViewController Picture in Picture issue

Tags: ios

I'm having a hard time understanding how to restore the PiP to fullscreen.

I press the PiP button and the screen minimizes. When I tap the PiP button on the minimized screen, the video is closed.

If I implement the delegate, I can use `playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture` to present the fullscreen again. However, this is called when the close button is tapped. This seems like it should be default behavior. The attached image shows what I am hoping to [image: achieve].

Comment: I still can't distinguish when user taps `close` vs `fullscreen` buttons. Did you find a solution? `restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler` for some reason is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't understand the difference between: `playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture` which is when the video is stopped and `restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler` when the Pip is tapped

Comment: how to detect play button on pip mode because when we pause video to full screen and enable pip mode in pause only the i have to tap many times on play button to start the video can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should present `playerViewController` again at

`playerViewControllerWillStopPictureInPicture(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController)`

or

`playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController)`

or

`playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)`